# Screen resolution issue with html

Tags: html, css, jsp

i develop my web based application system using java.When i design the pages i have to use position attribute for some elements to customize thier position in the page Like :

`<table style="position: absolute;top: 100px;">`

When i change the resolution of pc the element's position is changed.Any Suggestions to make element's position fixed
thanks

Comment: This isn't really answerable. You've styled it so the element is taken out of normal flow and positioned 100px from the top of its containing block, and that clearly isn't what you want — but you've provided no context or clue about what is is that you *do* want.

Comment: @Harry Joy — simply switching to a percentage almost certainly won't solve anything. Font sizes can change. Window widths can change. There are lots of factors impacting the position of the table and or other content.

Answer (score 1):

try it with:

```
position: fixed
```

fixed: The element is positioned relative to the browser window

Comment: oh you mean you change the display resolution and not size from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Any more details? As far as i understand, your table will move because 100px might be smaller or bigger depending on resolution. You may try with some other units, like "5%" or "em", they are a little less depending of resolution.

Comment: "Bigger" and "Smaller" are almost certainly beside the point. Abs Pos Layouts get screwed by how other content flows.

Answer (score 0):

Make the element that contains the `table` have `position:relative`. Then the absolutely positioned element will be positioned relative to it's parent.

Example:

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper" style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%;">
        <table style="position:absolute;top:100px;">
            <tr>
                <td>...
            ...
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```